# preg_replace expression can't include string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Being driven up the wall here. I've looked at other posts where there's a regex negative lookahead but for some reason I can't get it to work. Probably missing something very easy but after a couple of hours trying various options I need help!

So, I'm trying to find a pattern for preg_replace which searches through code for href links which IGNORES any containing a particular domain AND also IGNORES any which include a js reference called *data-fancybox*.

In the following it must ignore the first 3 which contain *data-fancybox* and also ignore #4 the *youtube* link. It should only find the last 2.

1. `<a href="https://youtube.com/" data-fancybox>`
2. `<a href="https://example.com/" data-fancybox>`
3. `<a href="https://vimeo.com/" data-fancybox>`
4. `<a href="https://youtube.com/">`
5. `<a href="https://example.com/">`
6. `<a href="https://vimeo.com/">`

When I try this:

`<a href=.*((youtube|data-fancybox)).*>`

It picks out the first 4 and ignores the last two. But when I try to turn this negative so it only picks out the last 2, it ends up picking them all out:

`<a href=.*(?!(youtube|data-fancybox)).*>`

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: why not ? if (!preg_match($pattern,$string)):

Comment: maybe this could help https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I can't user '? if (!preg_match($pattern,$string)):' because the preg_match needs to go through a large block of HTML text in which are various href links; it needs to pick out certain links and adjust them before returning the block of HTML

Answer (score 0):

You should specify all characters before of occurrence of the text that you are interested youtube.com for instance. To detect links that are not youtube.com

```
$pattern = '/(<a href=\"https:\/\/(?!youtube.com).*)/';
$string[] = '<a href="https://youtube.com/" data-fancybox>';
$string[] = '<a href="https://example.com/" data-fancybox>';
$string[] = '<a href="https://vimeo.com/" data-fancybox>';
$string[] = '<a href="https://youtube.com/">';
$string[] = '<a href="https://example.com/">';
$string[] = '<a href="https://vimeo.com/">';
foreach ($string as $key=>$str)
{
    if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches))
        echo "$key valid<BR>";
    else
        echo "$key not valid<BR>";
}
```

To detect link that are not data-fancybox

```
$pattern = '/(.*\" (?!data-fancybox)|.*\">)/';
```

Comment: That's a step closer; but does this mean it's not possible though to have a pattern which negates both 'youtube' OR 'data-fancybox' then as we can't specify the string which occurs before 'data-fancybox'?

Comment: when you write something like q(?!youtube.com) you are asking for a q character that is not followed by youtube.com. As far as I know, you always needs to specify this character, in this case q. The problem with your pattern is that you don' specify a character you simple say .* there are several characters that are not followed by youtube.com that is the reason all sentences are valid

Comment: to detect data-fancibox you could try $pattern = '/.*\" (data-fancybox).*/';

Comment: to detect with no data-fancibox: $pattern = '/(.*\" (?!data-fancybox)|.*\">)/';

Comment: doing an OR with both results: $pattern = '/<a href=\"https:\/\/(?!youtube.com).*|(.*\" (?!data-fancybox)|.*\">)/';

Comment: Unfortunately the OR pattern doesn't work as it's not possible AFAIK to have a variable BEFORE the lookahead. The string 'data-fancybox' could have any domain preceding it.

Comment: ok but the pattern as it was built doesn't matter the domain preceding it, please look carefully to the pattern: '/(.*\" (?!data-fancybox)|.*\">)/' the pattern starts from "<space>  the pattern ask for a " followed by space and not followed by data-fancybox

Comment: Well I'm afraid I'm still completely lost here. I put the pattern (and many, many, variations) into regex101 and it still doesn't match the right links. Perhaps it's just not possible?
https://regex101.com/r/K1TI38/4

Comment: the first condition: not to be youtube.com $pattern = '/(<a href=\"https:\/\/(?!youtube.com).*)/';

Comment: the second conditoon: not to be followed by data-fancybox: $pattern = '/(.*\" (?!data-fancybox)|.*\">)/';

Comment: what you are looking for is a combination of this two condition FIRST AND SECOND, so only 4,5 are valid, right ?

Comment: if I use OR condition it works: $pattern = '/(<a href=\"https:\/\/(?!youtube.com).*)|(.*\" (?!data-fancybox)|.*\">)/';

Comment: but to do ANd condition it is not working , I don't know why, sorry... $pattern = '/(<a href=\"https:\/\/(?!youtube.com).*)&&(.*\" (?!data-fancybox)|.*\">)/';

Comment: Yeah that's right, just the <a href,,,> tags in the bottom paragraph. It does seem the AND condition doesn't work with lookahead which is a real shame. Thanks for your time into looking at this though.