# PHP - preg_replace : no replace if data attribute is found in image

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to clean some pages from my blog and modify the images tags by using preg_replace. When an image has been cleaned, I add the data attribute data-updated to avoid modifying them a second time.

```
$final =  preg_replace('/<img(.*?)>/', '<img$1 data-updated=\'1\'>', $final);
```

But the next time I run the cleaning, the data-updated attribute is added a second time. I could do a str_replace to remove the additional data-updated but I'd like to avoid adding it through a regex in the first place.

i have tried using [^data-updated] with no success and I have found a similar post here:
[preg_replace expression can't include string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289937/preg-replace-expression-cant-include-string)
but replacing data-fancy by data-updated doesn't work

Is there a way to only add data-updated if it's not already there? There are many other tags in the  so I need to be able to check the presence of data-updated anywhere in the img tag

Here is an example of such an image:

```
<img srcset="xxx" src="yyy" loading="lazy" data-style="aspect-ratio:4/3;" data-placeholder="4-3" data-updated="y" alt="" width="100%">
```

Thanks!
Laurent

Comment: `[^data-updated]` negates a character class, here specifically not matching `adeptu-`. You can't use that syntax for negating strings. If you do want to use regex, you'd want to use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested structures like HTML are notoriously difficult to parse with regular expressions, because those structures are *irregular*. Not to mention that what you explicitly need is a *parser* since you need to test for the presence of attributes before making modifications.

For this, there is [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Eg:

```php
$html = <<<_E_
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <img src="/images/foo.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img someattr="yes" src="/images/bar.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
_E_;

$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHtml($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

foreach($d->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
    if( $node->attributes->getNamedItem('someattr') === null ) {
        $node->setAttribute('someattr', 'alsoyes');
    }
}

echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <img src="/images/foo.jpg" someattr="alsoyes">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img someattr="yes" src="/images/bar.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are right, it's the best approach, I was using a DOM parser to create the clean image, I now use it to mark it as clean and wrap it into a div without using regex. Thanks for pointing out!